# mingw32-g++.exe: Internal error: Aborted (program collect2)

Tags: c++

On each and every C++ program that I try to compile and run I get this error message:
Linking console executable: C:\Dev-Cpp\MalikChapter2\NewFriends\Friends\main.exe
mingw32-g++.exe: Internal error: Aborted (program collect2)
Please submit a full bug report.
See http://www.mingw.org/bugs.shtml> for instructions.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings

I cannot run any of my programs.
Please help

Comment: That's an ICE. "*Please submit a full bug report"*. Are you asking us if the code that you haven't posted is valid?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am trying to use CODEBLOCKS.

Comment: My Dev-cpp compiler was working fine all along but now it no longer works.

Comment: I think you have reached a wrong site. You should be on http://www.mingw.org/bugs.shtml

Comment: I have solved this problem. This question can now be closed